# mysql select all from one table and check another table for ID and status

Tags: mysql, sql

currently I have simple mysql `SELECT` query printed below.

```
  "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE views > $views_min ORDER BY $rating_or_something_other DESC LIMIT $index , $pics_per_page";
```

**I want to find all pictures not on hold, but problem is that hold status is at the other table:**

Table `pictures` have `pictures.gallery_id` column and I want to check `galleries.id` table for this `id` and my last point is `gallery.hold` status. Based on these data I want to get as a result only all `pictures.*` that is not on hold (by gallery).

I am trying something like this, but seems need to use `JOINS` ?

```
  "SELECT p.*, g.id, g.hold FROM pictures AS p, galleries AS g
    WHERE p.views > $views_min AND p.gallery_id = g.id AND g.hold <> 1 ORDER BY p.rating(?) DESC LIMIT $index, $pics_per_page;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to prevent the usage of a join? It's as simple as this:

```
SELECT p.*, g.id, g.hol FROM pictures AS p 
 INNER JOIN galleries as g ON g.id = p.gallery_id
WHERE p.views > $views AND g.hold <> 1
ORDER BY p.rating(?) DESC 
LIMIT $index, $pics_per_page;
```

Comment: thanks it works. only one problem. `ID` fields from two table also merged :(((

Comment: Then just join that two tables into the select: 
`inner join table2 as t2 on t2.id = p.t2_id
inner join table3 as t3 on t3.id = p.t3_id`